# Cassandra MultiNode cluster nodestatus showing only one node

Tags: cassandra

Created a 3 node cluster by configuring below properties.

cluster_name 
num_tokens 
data_file_directories 
commitlog_directory 
seed_provider 
listen_address 
rpc_address 
snitch (GossipingPropertyFileSnitch)

When running nodetool -host hostip status command, it shows only one node. It is not showing all 3 nodes.

I have below ports open 7000,7001,9160,7199,9042

I haven't setup any token and left to default.

What might be the issue ?

Comment: update the cassandra-rackdc.properties for the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch? Anything in the logs? Might wanna double check seed_provider and listen_address.

Comment: Yes. Specified dc and rack in all the nodes in cassandra-rackdc.properties. Nothing in the cassandra.log and system.log.

Comment: were your nodes started before you configured the cassandra.yaml?

Comment: Yes..will that cause any problems ?

Comment: try turning everything off, wipe /var/lib/cassandra (or wherever you configured it for), and turn everything back on.

Comment: I tried that before. Removed /var/lib/cassandra and then created /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog and /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches. Still the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73789/discussion-between-ramana-uppala-and-chris-lohfink).